# Using custom validation functions in CakePHP to check dependent fields

Tags: cakephp

If there is a field `data['Form']['gender']` `then if 'female'`, `then ['Form']['is_pregnant']` must be `'yes'` or `'no'`.

```
public $validate = array(
    'is_pregnant' => array(
        'rule'    => array('checkGender', 'female'),
        'message' => 'If female, please answer if pregnant.'
    )
);

public function checkGender($check, $gender) {
    if($check == $gender)
       return true;
    else
       return false;

}
```

I don't think what I've done above is right.  Maybe the wrong way round.  I'm also trying to turn this into a general purpose function where a field1 value has to be `[x,y,z]` if a `field2` value is `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public $validate = array(
    'is_pregnant' => array(
        'rule'    => array('checkGender'),
        'message' => 'If female, please answer if pregnant.'
    )
);


public function checkGender() {
    if($this->data[$this->alias]['gender'] == 'female' && empty($this->data[$this->alias]['is_pregnant'])) {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```